# JW Player HTML5-only mode

Tags: html, mp4, jwplayer

I'm trying to setup JW Player to playback in HTML5-only mode.
Apparently it doesn't work and I only get to see the flash fallback.

**My setup:**

```
<div id='videoContainer'>This text will be replaced</div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('videoContainer').setup({
      'flashplayer': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
      'file': '/videos/clip_01.mp4',
      'image': '/images/preview.jpg',
      'skin': '/jwplayer/skins/lulu.zip',
      'backcolor': 'FFFFFF',
      'frontcolor': '000000',
      'lightcolor': '000000',
      'screencolor': '000000',
      'controlbar': 'bottom',
      'width': '640',
      'height': '480',

      'modes': [
          { type: "html5",
            config: {
              file: "/videos/clip_01.mp4"
            }
          },
          //I commented this line out so it doesn't fallback to flash
          //{ type: "flash", src: "/jwplayer/player.swf" },
          { type: "download" }
      ]
    });
  </script>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this feature not yet available?

Comment: Which browser are you trying this in? If a non MP4 supporting browser such as Firefox or Opera is being used, then it will default to Flash.

Comment: Thank you, I guess this is the answer.
I was using Firefox.

Comment: Try a WebM or OGG file in firefox and see what happens, this would confirm it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a **non MP4 supporting browser** such as **Firefox** or **Opera** is being used, then it will default to Flash.

*– Ian Devlin Jan 23 '12 at 14:11*